# Jquery - find <input> with 'hidden' in form and change css in element before

Tags: jquery, html, css

As described in Question i need to change the line-height in a form, because i have to much gaps between empty/hidden inputs.

CSS:

```
p { line-height:1.6em; }
```

HTML:

```
<form class="webform">
 <p>
   <input type="hidden"></input>
 </p>
 <p>
   <input type="text"></input>
 </p>
</form>
```

I already tried that, but it´s not completed:

```
$("form[class='webform'] p").css("line-height", "0em");
```

So, it changes all css within the Form, but i just want change the height of the hidden once.

Comment: Just as an aside, wouldn't `hide()` make more sense that setting the line-height to 0?

Comment: `$("form.webform input:hidden").parent().hide();` should do the trick

Comment: Hidden inputs are typically just inside the form and not inside elements (like `<p>`). Are you generating the `type="hidden"` on the fly?

Comment: @MCG in css styles remove # near to the p tag. # used for the id selector not for the element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) to select `p` elements that contain hidden `input` elements:

```
$("form.webform p:has(input[type='hidden'])").css("line-height", "0em");
```

It would probably make more sense just to hide the element though:

```
$("form.webform p:has(input[type='hidden'])").hide();
```

Comment: Yeah! Of Course! That´s it! Thanks! That´s smart!